# User-friendly DSP for high-frequency application?

Tags: video-processing

I've been doing some work with creating visual output on oscilloscopes using audio; here are some examples:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UJ8-vySqEAI

This is using Max/MSP to read from a buffer of 3d geometry as audio output to an oscilloscope screen. I'm interested in doing transformations on full frames of video as well, like a digital/analog hybrid version of the old Scanimate machines from the 70s:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wTO3CKM2Yy0)

But at 44100 samples/second, I don't have the bandwidth to keep a frame of video on the screen at a high enough scan rate without the signal degrading.

What I'd like to do is to use something like MiniDSP to:
1. Load a frame of pixels (monochrome) into a buffer
2. Read out the buffer to modulate the beam's brightness and move it along a raster scan path at high speed (around 60fps ideally)
3. Add LFOs to modulate the scan path to warp the image

This requires a high sampling rate for output, probably higher than normal audio rates for NTSC video, and I know MiniDSP is mainly for audio applications. I'm wondering if you can recommend a solution, ideally one that has friendly features like USB connectivity and C++ compiler, or am I dreaming? Can MiniDSP be overclocked to work at higher rates for output?

Thanks very much for any help.